# How to stop pandas from corrupting None, from optional float optional Int into floating with NAN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-typing

Creating a `pandas.DataFrame` corrupts column types, with `Optional` types in a way that changes the meaning of the values.

```py
import pandas as pd
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional


@dataclass
class ExampleData:
    a: int
    b: Optional[int] = None
    c: Optional[str] = None
    d: Optional[float] = None


x = ExampleData(3)
y = ExampleData(7, 6, 'yesterday', 4.5)
z = ExampleData(9, 400, 'zebra', 3.4)
df = pd.DataFrame([x, y, z])
df
```

Notice that the resulting `int` column "b" is cohersed into a `float` column, and all instances from "b" and "d" which should be `Optional` numerics have cast `None` into `float('NaN')`, which is fundamentally a different value.

```
    a   b       c           d
0   3   NaN     None        NaN
1   7   6.0     yesterday   4.5
2   9   400.0   zebra       3.4
```

What I want is to be able to preserve the `int` column and the `None` value entries

```
    a   b       c           d
0   3   None    None        None
1   7   6       yesterday   4.5
2   9   400     zebra       3.4
```

I notice that

```
df['b'].convert_dtypes(int)
0    <NA>
1       6
2     400
Name: b, dtype: Int64
```

shows how `None` could be preserved without corrupting the data types.

Comment: Use `df = pd.DataFrame([x, y, z], dtype=object)`.

Comment: pandas isn't *corrupting* anything. it's doing exactly what it says it will do in the documentation. see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html. The performance of an object array is significantly worse than that of a fixed-type numeric array, so it's making well-characterized assumptions about your intent. You always have the option of sticking with objects if you wish.